# Difference between gänzlich and unbedingt?

Tags: translation

Like the title says: are these synonyms? I got *totally* as the translation of *gänzlich*, and *absolutely, definitely* for *unbedingt*.

Although, maybe I am using *totally* too "valleygirlishly"? And my English is off?

Comment: Please make an effort to use proper umlauts. Fixed it for you this time.

Comment: Online dictionaries, which are just provding a single word translation are not exactly serious references. Your words have so little overlap, that I don't understand the question.

Comment: I used collins hardcover from 80s college, fat one.  And looked at online sites with example sentences. Not sure what else you expect.  I see SE as next level up of research after that, if still questions.

Comment: Ingmar, I'm actually trying with the umlauts. Downloaded the ASCI numbet code things nd have printed and next to computer. This was a one off post from phone.  Will use comp in future. No clue how to asci number pad with phone.

Comment: You don't need that on a phone. Their keyboard has a neat function. Keep the key pressed and a small menu appears where you can select from all the accented variants of a character.

Comment: Tatsächlich.  Ha.  Du hast total recht.  I mean Sie.  

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- gänzlich, zur Gänze — wholly
- unbedingt — at all costs

Comment: Is it sort of like completely versus definitely?  Even the English is confusing me.

Comment: Not sure there is much more to explain? *gänzlich* derives from *das Ganze*, i.e. the total: it means wholly, fully, all of it. *unbedingt* means, literally, *unconditional(ly)*.

Comment: Like I said, the confusion is a little coming from the English, where totally has acquired casual usage from surfers and Valley girls and general public.  It could have been that German also has this issue.  See that sometimes, with subtleties of meaning. But it seems like this nuance of drift affects English only.  So that is a learning for me...hence the question.

Comment: *Du musst das total machen. Echt totaaal.* is indeed German slang. But not “valley girl”. They look at those big town bimbos with a face of disbelief and ask themselves what's wrong with the freshwater at that place.